# Count only cells that countain the number "1"

Tags: excel

I'm using `COUNTIF` to count all the cells that contains the number "1". Cell `A1` looks like this "1,5,7,11,15,101".

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A25;"*"&"1"&"*")
```

This gives me all the cells that has "1" somewhere in it - even 11 and 101. How can I count only cells that contain "1" and not "11","21","901" etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your numbers in cell splitted with comma `,` (as `1,5,7,11,15,101`), you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & 1 & ",";"," & SUBSTITUTE(A1:A25;" ";"") & ","))*1)
```

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & 1 & ",","," & A1:A25 & ","))*1)` worked ... somehow `;` doesnt work ... must be something to do with OS setup?

Comment: it depends on local settings, from OP's formula `=COUNTIF(A1:A25;"*"&"1"&"*")` I saw that his/her local settings required `;` as formula separator and that's why I'm used it in my formula

Comment: Amazing! However, this doesn't work if the cell doesn't start with "1". Anyway to fix this?

Comment: as I see, it works for me.are you sure it doesn't work? can you give a value of cell when it doesn't work propertly?

Comment: do you have spaces in your cell?

Comment: SORRY! I was wrong. I added spaces between my numbers "1, 2, 3". It works! THANKS ALOT GUYS!

Comment: btw, I've fixed issue with spaces) see updated formula:)

Comment: You guys! This is amazing! One more question. If my cell values are "op 1, op 2, op 11, op 55" etc. Is this possible?

Comment: clarify please, your cell value `"op 1, op 2, op 11, op 55"` and you need to find `op 1`?

Comment: `1)` if your cell contains `"op 1, op 2, op 11, op 55"` and you need to find `"op 1"`, use `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & "op 1" & ",";"," & SUBSTITUTE(A1:A25;" ";"") & ","))*1)`. Else, `2)` if your cell contains `"op 1, op 2, op 11, op 55"` and you need to find `"1"`, use `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & 1 & ",";"," & SUBSTITUTE(A1:A25;" ";",") & ","))*1)`

Comment: One more question. Maybe I should have made a new entry for this... Now I'm able to identify which cells contain "1". Is it possible to use this information to SUM values from the adjacent cells? If one or more cells in range A1:A10 contain 1 then sum all true valuesfrom B1:B10. Just like SUMIF

Comment: This is what I would like to work. =SUMIF("," & A1:A10 & ",";"," & C1 & ",";B1:B10)

Comment: Moved this question to a New Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758723/sumif-how-can-i-sum-values-based-only-on-certain-letters-numbers-from-cell

Comment: I think you already got the correct answer in your new tread: change `*1` to `*(B1:B25)` as follows: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & 1 & ",";"," & SUBSTITUTE(A1:A25;" ";"") & ","))*(B1:B25))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

**=COUNTIF(A1:A25,"1")**

Comment: Why not???.........the formula counts only those cells that contain the single character **1** .

Comment: Please review the question again. His single cell contains a string (of numbers).

Comment: My formula would exclude a cell like     **1,2,3**

Comment: Yes ... the question is seeking all those cell counts which have 1 in it ... even if its 1,2,3 ... but it should not count the cell if it contains values such as 7,9,11.

Comment: Check out simoco's formula ... I think thats the correct solution.

Comment: simoco's formula will count a cell like **1,10** .........is this what the OP wants??

Answer (score 0):

As long you dont have more than one 1 in a cell you can still use countif:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A25;"1,*")+COUNTIF(A1:A25;"*,1,*")+COUNTIF(A1:A25;"*,1")
```