# SUMIF, how can I sum values based only on certain letters/numbers from cell?

Tags: excel

In my range A1:B25 I have categories (A1:A25) and numbers (B1:B25). The cells in column A contains numbers seperated by comma "1,2,3,11,1056,392" etc.

This formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & 1 & ",";"," & SUBSTITUTE(A1:A25;" ";"") & ","))*1)`

is counting all the cells which contains the number "1" and excludes "11", "101" etc.

Perfect!

But I'm looking for a formula that gives me the cells containing "1" in column A and then sums all the corresponding cells in column B.

Like this:

`=SUMIF("," & A1:A25 & ",";"," & C1 & ",";B1:B25)`

C1 is my check-up-value ("1")

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you have more than one 1 in the same cell like 2,1,3,1,5

Comment: instead of *1 multiply by the range containing the numbers you want to sum... replace *1 by * B1:B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your numbers in column A are separated by only commas, This formula should do the trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(",1,",","&A1:A25&","))),B1:B25)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out! With substitute, len, sumifs, countifs you name it :) Thanks you, John! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful so for counting text ignore column without a helper column of 1 and 0 too:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("y",A1:A25)))),B1:B25)
```